# Sort columns in order of decreasing variance in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I wish to order the columns of a dataset in order of decreasing column variance but I have had no luck in doing so. This is what I have so far:

```
og_data <- og_data[, sort(apply(og_data, 2, var), decreasing=TRUE)]
```

Now, I know this doesn't work since `sort(apply(og_data, 2, var), decreasing=TRUE)` returns the variance values of the columns in order of decreasing variance. I have no idea how to extract the column indexes from this which is what I would need to use. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need `order` instead of `sort`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not give reproducible data for me to work with
you can try this method below

```
# sorting examples using the mtcars dataset
attach(mtcars)

# sort by mpg
new_data <- mtcars[order(mpg),]

# sort by mpg and cyl
new_data <- mtcars[order(mpg, cyl),]

#sort by mpg (ascending) and cyl (descending)
new_data <- mtcars[order(mpg, -cyl),]
```

hope this solved your question

Answer (score 0):

Since the goal is to order the *columns* of the data frame by descending variance, we calculate the variances and use `order()` to sort by descending variance.

We'll use `mtcars` to illustrate, given the absence of a minimal reproducible example:

```
mtcars[,order(apply(mtcars,2,var),decreasing=TRUE)]
```

...and the output:

```
                     disp  hp  mpg  qsec cyl carb    wt gear drat vs am
Mazda RX4           160.0 110 21.0 16.46   6    4 2.620    4 3.90  0  1
Mazda RX4 Wag       160.0 110 21.0 17.02   6    4 2.875    4 3.90  0  1
Datsun 710          108.0  93 22.8 18.61   4    1 2.320    4 3.85  1  1
Hornet 4 Drive      258.0 110 21.4 19.44   6    1 3.215    3 3.08  1  0
Hornet Sportabout   360.0 175 18.7 17.02   8    2 3.440    3 3.15  0  0
Valiant             225.0 105 18.1 20.22   6    1 3.460    3 2.76  1  0
Duster 360          360.0 245 14.3 15.84   8    4 3.570    3 3.21  0  0
Merc 240D           146.7  62 24.4 20.00   4    2 3.190    4 3.69  1  0
Merc 230            140.8  95 22.8 22.90   4    2 3.150    4 3.92  1  0
Merc 280            167.6 123 19.2 18.30   6    4 3.440    4 3.92  1  0
Merc 280C           167.6 123 17.8 18.90   6    4 3.440    4 3.92  1  0
Merc 450SE          275.8 180 16.4 17.40   8    3 4.070    3 3.07  0  0
Merc 450SL          275.8 180 17.3 17.60   8    3 3.730    3 3.07  0  0
Merc 450SLC         275.8 180 15.2 18.00   8    3 3.780    3 3.07  0  0
Cadillac Fleetwood  472.0 205 10.4 17.98   8    4 5.250    3 2.93  0  0
Lincoln Continental 460.0 215 10.4 17.82   8    4 5.424    3 3.00  0  0
Chrysler Imperial   440.0 230 14.7 17.42   8    4 5.345    3 3.23  0  0
Fiat 128             78.7  66 32.4 19.47   4    1 2.200    4 4.08  1  1
Honda Civic          75.7  52 30.4 18.52   4    2 1.615    4 4.93  1  1
Toyota Corolla       71.1  65 33.9 19.90   4    1 1.835    4 4.22  1  1
Toyota Corona       120.1  97 21.5 20.01   4    1 2.465    3 3.70  1  0
Dodge Challenger    318.0 150 15.5 16.87   8    2 3.520    3 2.76  0  0
AMC Javelin         304.0 150 15.2 17.30   8    2 3.435    3 3.15  0  0
Camaro Z28          350.0 245 13.3 15.41   8    4 3.840    3 3.73  0  0
Pontiac Firebird    400.0 175 19.2 17.05   8    2 3.845    3 3.08  0  0
Fiat X1-9            79.0  66 27.3 18.90   4    1 1.935    4 4.08  1  1
Porsche 914-2       120.3  91 26.0 16.70   4    2 2.140    5 4.43  0  1
Lotus Europa         95.1 113 30.4 16.90   4    2 1.513    5 3.77  1  1
Ford Pantera L      351.0 264 15.8 14.50   8    4 3.170    5 4.22  0  1
Ferrari Dino        145.0 175 19.7 15.50   6    6 2.770    5 3.62  0  1
Maserati Bora       301.0 335 15.0 14.60   8    8 3.570    5 3.54  0  1
Volvo 142E          121.0 109 21.4 18.60   4    2 2.780    4 4.11  1  1
>
```

To cross-check the results, we'll sort and print the vector of variances:

```
#cross-check variances

variances <- apply(mtcars,2,var)
variances[order(variances,decreasing = TRUE)]
```

Notice that the ordering of the vector matches the ordering of the columns from the prior operation.

```
        disp           hp          mpg         qsec          cyl         carb 
1.536080e+04 4.700867e+03 3.632410e+01 3.193166e+00 3.189516e+00 2.608871e+00 
          wt         gear         drat           vs           am 
9.573790e-01 5.443548e-01 2.858814e-01 2.540323e-01 2.489919e-01 
>
```